# How can I create a button with default behavior in win32

Tags: winapi, button

I have been trying to create a button with the default behavior i.e when the user press ENTER, the button is fired.
I created the button with the WS_TABSTOP style and sent it the BM_SETSTYLE message with BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON has WPARAM parameter 
but it's still not working.

```
HWND hwnd_Ok = CreateWindow("button", "Ok", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP, 285, 195, 70, 25, hwnd, (HMENU)OK_BUTTON, NULL, NULL);


SendMessage(hwnd_Ok, BM_SETSTYLE, (WPARAM)BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 4):

I am trying to handle `WM_GETDLGCODE` for getting `WM_KEYDOWN` with `VK_RETURN` message in your control's WndProc. Sample code:

```
case WM_GETDLGCODE: {
  if(wParam==VK_RETURN) {
    return DLGC_WANTALLKEYS;
  }
}
break;
```

Answer (score 1):

The BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON is just a flag added to the button.  The behavior you describe (along with lots of other field navigation behavior) is actually implemented by [`IsDialogMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which you get for free is a modal dialog box.

If you're trying to handle this in your own window class (or a modeless dialog), you can add IsDialogMessage to your message loop to get the dialog-style handling.

Comment: Yes, I am handling it in a windows class that is running on another thread (if that matters).

Comment: Edited my message loop to this but still not working while(GetMessage(&msg, hwnd, NULL, NULL) > 0)
    {
     if(!IsDialogMessage(hwnd , &msg))
     {
      TranslateMessage(&msg);
      DispatchMessage(&msg);
      }
    }

Comment: That should be `GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)`, otherwise you won't be pumping messages for other windows using the same thread queue.

Comment: I have got it working on the first window (thanks to you for that) but it's still not working on the other window. I opened those windows on  different threads... CloseHandle(CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)CreateAboutBox, (LPVOID)hInstance, NULL, NULL));...

Comment: Am I to use GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL) on those separate windows also?