# how to execute code on enter key press in c++?

Tags: c++, winapi

In my application I have three edit box and a submit button. I am
executing some code on submit button click but I also want that if I press the Enter key that code should also execute.

My code is:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch(LOWORD(wParam))
    {
        case IDC_MAIN_BUTTON:
        {
            SendMessage(h_Name,WM_GETTEXT,sizeof(CName)/sizeof(CName[0]),reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(CName));
            SendMessage(h_Email,WM_GETTEXT,sizeof(CName)/sizeof(CEmail[0]),reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(CEmail));
            SendMessage(h_Phone,WM_GETTEXT,sizeof(CPhone)/sizeof(CPhone[0]),reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(CPhone));

            i = 1;

            EnableWindow( GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_MAIN_BUTTON),false);
            EnableWindow( GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_CLEAR_BUTTON),false);
            ShowWindow(GetDlgItem(hwnd, 3), SW_SHOW);
            SendMessage( hwndPrgBar, PBM_SETPOS, 0, 0 );
            SetTimer(hwnd, ID_TIMER, 10, NULL);
        }
        break;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the submit button the default button, so that pressing the enter key will have the same effect as clicking 'Submit'. Read the help for your IDE to see how to do this.

Comment: I already made my submit button as a default button as SendMessage(hwnd, DM_SETDEFID, (WPARAM)IDC_MAIN_BUTTON, 0); ,but it is not working.

Comment: Did you create the button with the BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON style? If using MFC, set DefaultButton to true in the button's properties.

Comment: I already did this but that is not working my button code is-
 
hWndButton=CreateWindowEx(NULL,"BUTTON","Submit",WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE |WS_CHILD| BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,100,100,80,24,hwnd,(HMENU)IDC_MAIN_BUTTON,(HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),NULL);
SendMessage(hWndButton,WM_SETFONT,NULL,MAKELPARAM(FALSE,0));
 
I also try this also-
 
SendMessage(hwnd, DM_SETDEFID, (WPARAM)IDC_MAIN_BUTTON, 0);

Comment: Are you creating this button inside a dialog box? I believe that the default button processing is done by the dialog box window procedure. If the button is not inside a dialog box, you might be able to call IsDialogMessage to make your window behave like a dialog box.

Comment: I think Adrian McCarthy's answers here may give you the information you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021817/how-can-i-create-a-button-with-default-behavior-in-win32