# Capture "enter key" so that pressing it replaces a "Button" in Winapi32

Tags: c++, winapi, enter

I want to be able to access the procedure of an event in two ways: with a Button and pressing enter.
I have the button code done:

```
        case BTN_1:
            char CAD[50];
            int N1, N2;
            GetDlgItemText(hwndDlg, EDIT1, CAD, 50);
            N1 =atoi(CAD); //Almacenando el contenido de CAD en N1 = int
            N1 - '0';
            base(N1, N2); //function
            SetDlgItemText(hwndDlg, EDIT2, cad1);
            return 0;
```

I know I have to put case WM_KEYDOWN, but how do I replace the key without having to rewrite all the code of the Button? or What would be the code to work with "enter key" in case WM_KEYDOWN?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put the common code into a function, and call that function from both handlers?

Comment: Related: [How can I create a button with default behavior in win32](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021817/how-can-i-create-a-button-with-default-behavior-in-win32)

Comment: Make the button be the default button and the dialog manager does it for you. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: More broadly don't write your entire program in your window procedure. Abstract actions away into separate functions for ease of re-use.